# Regex for matching a word within a sentence

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a C# regex to match a complete word within a sentence.

my sentence and pattern looks like this below.

```
 string mySentence = "There is no gain in this world without pain";

 string mypattern = string.Format(@"(?:(?<=^|\s)(?=\S)|(?<=\S|^)(?=\s)){0} (?:(?<=\S)(?=\s|$)|(?<=\s)(?=\S|$))", "pain");

 MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(mySentence, mypattern);
```

I do not get any match using the above pattern.

But if I use this pattern I get a match.

```
string mypattern = string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", "patient");
```

But the problem is it matches hyphen separated word like in-pain as well, where as I am looking for a complete word.

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Wait, what are the actual requirements? Match a search phrase enclosed with whitespaces? Or within word boundaries but not when preceded/followed with `-`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am looking to match a word, which can be followed or preceded by newline or whitespace. thanks

Comment: Ok, I provided both solutions, together with a non-regex one in case you only need to search for non-whitespace chunks of text in longer strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Scenario #1** *(word(s) not preceded/followed with hyphen)*

Use negative lookarounds `(?<!-)` (no `-` before the search phrase) and `(?!-)` (no `-` after the search phrase) together with `\b`:

```
var mypattern = string.Format(@"(?<!-)\b{0}\b(?!-)", Regex.Escape(search));
```

**Scenario #2** *(word(s) enclosed with whitespaces)*

> I am looking to match a word, which can be followed or preceded by newline or whitespace.

You need to use lookarounds like this:

```
var mypattern = string.Format(@"(?<!\S){0}(?!\S)", Regex.Escape(search));
```

The `(?<!\S)` lookaround (equal to `(?<=\s|^)`) requires a whitespace or start of string before the search word. The `(?!\S)` negative lookahead will require a whitespace symbol after the search word.

The `Regex.Escape` is a pre-caution step to make sure all special chars inside the search word are treated as  literal characters.

A note: if your "words" never contain a whitespace, you do not need a regex. Use

```
var search = "this";
var sentence = "There is no gain in this world without pain";
var isPresent = sentence.Split().Contains(search);
Console.Write(isPresent); // = > True
```

Comment: I tried this statement, There can be no gain without pain. but I found no matches, i think I forgot to tell you there can be a period or any special character following it,

Comment: So, `var mypattern = string.Format(@"(?<!-)\b{0}\b(?!-)", Regex.Escape(search));`?

Comment: I think this regex in Scenario #1 works for me :)- thank you

Comment: I tried this sentence, There pain's is no gain in this world without in-pain's. Over here it maches my pain's, is there a way, I get to match only occurances of pain and not pain's?

Comment: Replace `(?!-)` with `(?!-|['’]s\b)`. What about `pains'`?

Comment: I think it will be `(?!['’-])`. You will get false negatives if you have your search words inside quotes.